# Providing a meaningful default directory name in GIMP Scheme (script-Fu)

Tags: scheme, gimp, script-fu

I'm a total newbie to Scheme (about 1 week).
I'm registering a script for which the second parameter is an output directory name - via SF-DIRNAME. How do I supply a meaningful default to the front-end widget that does not use host platform-specific names? Ideally, I'd like it to be '/Users/[username]' - or if possible - the Scheme equivalent of ${PWD}. As an illustration, when you create a new image and hit 'Save' for the first time, the default directory there is '/Users/[username]/Documents' - so it must be possible. How does the widget know what your user home directory is? How can this be referred to in the default field of the registration statement? Finally, it would be really nice if Gimp could 'remember' which output directory was selected last time (within the scope of the lifetime of the Gimp instance) and offer that up as the default on the second and subsequent invocations of the script. I've scoured hundreds of other people's scripts, the Gimp community pages and the Scheme documentation and I've found, literally, nothing on this requirement. Thanks in advance. VV

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gimp uses the GTKFileChooser widget, and there is nothing you can do in your script to make it different from the other instances of `GTKFileChooser` used in Gimp.

But what you supply as a default name can be a variable, it doesn't need to be a static string, and it can be set by any means available in to your Scheme interpreter at the time of registration (looking for the HOME environment variable, for instance).

Btw, if you are new to this, write your scripts in Python, it is both easier and more powerful.

Comment: +1 "if you are new to this, write your scripts in Python, it is both easier and more powerful." can't give enough emphasis for that. I can only recommend scheme/lisp for the fun of writing scheme/lisp itself, just like a crossword puzzle.

Comment: Thank you for this Xenoid! I totally take Jsbueno's point about 'crossword' puzzle! Getting it to read HOME was actually what I was aiming at but none of the env vars defined in the rc file seem to work - unless I'm accessing them incorrectly. There is precious little in-depth doc on Scheme anywhere. I might look at the Python route for long-term 'stability'.

Answer (score 0):

found (getenv "HOME") as script-fu api command works

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).